# KDE 4 find files/folders

Tags: linux, kde, kde-4, desktop-search, file-search

For some reason, every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Dolphin or Konqueror, the "Find Files/Folders" dialog remembers "ruby1.9", which I entered in the filename field a long time back.  Clearing it or using something else doesn't change what the default value in the dialog, either.  And it's a pain because I have to remember to clear it manually if I search from one of the other tabs, as I generally do.

[image: Screenshot of KDE 4's find files/folders dialog.]

What's the best way to make the dialog stop remembering that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the file

```
~/.kde/share/config/kfindrc
```

There will be a line as follows:

```
 Patterns[$e]=leather,pineapples,hello,*
```

delete some or all of the entries after the equals sign to get rid of them from the search history.

credit: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3036127&postcount=5